# How to fix Mono Shared Runtime is not supported when running UI Test

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest

This is a very frustrating issue and I have found lots of unhelpful articles, especially since they all point to Visual Studio 2019.

I get this issue when trying to run a Xamarin.UITest project.

```
System.Exception : Mono Shared Runtime is not supported. This can be resolved by changing the project configuration or using a Release build.
```

#### CSPROJ FILE

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Test|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Test</OutputPath>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AndroidManagedSymbols>true</AndroidManagedSymbols>
    <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>false</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
    <AotAssemblies>false</AotAssemblies>
    <EnableLLVM>false</EnableLLVM>
    <AndroidEnableProfiledAot>false</AndroidEnableProfiledAot>
    <BundleAssemblies>false</BundleAssemblies>
    <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>true</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
    <AndroidSupportedAbis>armeabi-v7a;x86;x86_64;arm64-v8a</AndroidSupportedAbis>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

#### Properties

[image: Properties]

Comment: Sounds like its finding the wrong .apk file. Anything helpful in [UITest Demo source and instructions](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-Xamarin.UITest-Demo)?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I wish that was the case, I am pointing to the file path of my test apk. Even when I use .InstalledApp() to target the installed Test apk on the phone I sitll get the same issue.

Comment: I wonder if it could be seeing a SharedMonoFramework on the device, from an earlier debug test run. Uninstall the app from device. Power off the device (probably not needed, but. when strange things happen…). Now should be in a clean state. Delete all bin and obj folders in solution.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve that seemed to be the issue. I did a factory reset and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OP (Original Poster aka question-asker) seems to be doing everything right, in specifying the apk.

It appears that a SharedMonoFramework was still on the device, associated with the project's bundle id, from an earlier debug test run.

The app needed to be **completely** removed from the device.

One of these approaches:

- Manually delete app from device.
- Command prompt `adb uninstall com.yourcompany.yourapp` (the bundle id).
- Factory reset the device.

Comment: Update: this only works when I use `.InstalledApp()` for some odd reason. If I refer to the actual .APK file then I get the same error. This is problematic as AppCenter uses an APK for tests

Answer (score 0):

The solution for us was to update the Xamarin.UITest NuGet package.
Our old version was 3.2.7 and we upgraded it to 4.1.4

Problem solved :-)